# regex to extract values after last occurence of greater than symbol(>) / any special character and remove digits

Tags: java

Example:

```
<E72327> An exception occurred within fCMN_TREProductInstanceCreate& while calling EV_ProdInstInsert&: <E05560> This Product Instance does not reference a Customer 8482195 that covers the entire duration..
```

Output:

```
This Product Instance does not reference a Customer that covers the entire duration..
```

Comment: How does the stirng containing ">" look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal greedy behavior of the `*` operator works in your favor in this case.  You can simply use the following regex pattern:

```
.*>(.*)
```

Here, the `.*>` will consume everything up to and including the *last* closing bracket.  Then, we capture the remainder of the string.

```
String input = "<E72327> An exception occurred within fCMN_TREProductInstanceCreate& while calling EV_ProdInstInsert&: <E05560> This Product Instance does not reference a Customer 8482195 that covers the entire duration..";
input = input.replaceAll(".*>(.*)", "$1")
             .replaceAll("\\d+\\s*", "");
System.out.println(input);
```

**Output:**

```
 This Product Instance does not reference a Customer that covers the entire duration..
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: possible in second replace would be better to use `\\d+\\s*` to prevent double spaces after digits are removed.